# Formula for calculating user experience

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, formula

I would like (without using a gem) to create a level and experience point system for my users.

When creating his account, he starts level 0 with 0 experience points. To reach level 1 he will need 10 additional points, for a total of 10 points. For level 3 he will need 30 additional points, for a total of 60 experience points. Each additional level requires 10 more experience points. (see example below).

```
Level  |  Total XP  |  XP for next level|
----------------------------------------|
0      |    0       |    10             |
1      |    10      |    20             |               
2      |    30      |    30             |
3      |    60      |    40             |
4      |    100     |    50             |
5      |    150     |    60             |
etc...
```

I would like an xp column in my user table that would represent the total experience of a user.

In my view I would like to display its level. But what is the formula for calculating this?

Let's imagine that my user has 157 experience points in total. Which corresponds to a level 5. How to calculate a level only via the total experience points and how to calculate this regardless of its total experience point whether it is 38 like 369 or 4393.

Comment: Possibly a question better suited to https://math.stackexchange.com but it's an interesting one. I'll keep thinking to see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: I know you asked for a formula, but what do you think about using ActiveRecord? Something like: "Level.where('? >= total_xp', user_xp).order(:total_exp).first.level". A suggestion, in case this option has not crossed your mind.

Comment: `Total XP = Level * (Level + 1) * 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted. It's more of an algorithm than a formula, but here is a method that will return the proper level based on the experience  given. Think of the `bar` variable like the bar you have to get over to meet a new level, and think of the `step` variable like the amount of experience added between each level (as you describe in your right-most column).

```
def calculate_level(experience)
  level = 0
  bar   = 10
  step  = 10
  while experience >= bar
    level += 1
    step  += 10
    bar   += step
  end
  level
end
```

Example output:

```
irb> calculate_level(0)   # => 0
irb> calculate_level(9)   # => 0
irb> calculate_level(10)  # => 1
irb> calculate_level(11)  # => 1
irb> calculate_level(29)  # => 1
irb> calculate_level(30)  # => 2
irb> calculate_level(31)  # => 2
irb> calculate_level(59)  # => 2
irb> calculate_level(60)  # => 3
irb> calculate_level(61)  # => 3
irb> calculate_level(99)  # => 3
irb> calculate_level(100) # => 4
irb> calculate_level(101) # => 4
irb> calculate_level(149) # => 4
irb> calculate_level(150) # => 5
irb> calculate_level(151) # => 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the inverse of my above comment and take the `floor`:

```
def calculate_level experience
  (Math.sqrt(0.2 * experience + 0.25) - 0.5).floor
end
```

Comment: Nice job, Matt!

Answer (score 0):

You can use such "formula"

```
def calculate_level(experience)
  (1..).find { |i| (experience -= 10 * i).negative? } - 1
end
```

Just decrease experience on 10x steps every time and check if result is not negative

```
calculate_level(0)
# => 0

calculate_level(9)
# => 0

calculate_level(10)
# => 1

calculate_level(11)
# => 1

calculate_level(29)
# => 1

calculate_level(30)
# => 2

calculate_level(31)
# => 2

calculate_level(59)
# => 2

calculate_level(60)
# => 3

calculate_level(61)
# => 3

calculate_level(99)
# => 3

calculate_level(100)
# => 4

calculate_level(101)
# => 4

calculate_level(149)
# => 4

calculate_level(150)
# => 5

calculate_level(151)
# => 5

calculate_level(209)
# => 5

calculate_level(210)
# => 6
```

Comment: It might be my version of Ruby, but `(1..).find` returns a syntax error.

Comment: @BenFenner Ruby 2.6 introduced endless ranges 4 years ago. Try `1..Float::INFINITY` instead